# Adding a table to a search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function searching different criteria but I want to add a table to be searched.

The sql statement is:

```
$sql_main = " select distinct s.prefix, istore.* from image_store istore inner join
              image_size isz on 
              istore.id = isz.imgid inner join size s on isz.isize = s.id 
              inner join image_to_categories ic on istore.id = ic.imgid
              where s.id = 1 and istore.istatus = 1 ";
```

I need to add to the search:

**select catname from categories**

```
Update: The table structures

categories: id, catname, par_id

image_to_categories: id, imgid, catid
```

Comment: please show 'categories' and 'image_to_categories' table structures

Comment: The table structures...
categories: id, catname, par_id
image_to_categories: id, imgid, catid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the query you were searching for? I have displayed it in a more readable way.

```
$sql_main = " 

select distinct

s.prefix, istore.*, c.catname

from image_store istore 

inner join image_size isz on 
istore.id = isz.imgid 

inner join size s 
on isz.isize = s.id 

inner join image_to_categories ic 
on istore.id = ic.imgid

inner join categories c
on ic.catid = c.id

where s.id = 1 and istore.istatus = 1

";
```

I have added a join to the categories table at the end, and displayed the category at the top.

I hope this helps.

Philippe

Comment: The final code is like this: (The last inner join worked on ic.imgid) cat id was repeating the results more than once... Cheers!

Comment: $sql_main = " 
select distinct 
s.prefix, istore.*, c.catname
from image_store istore

inner join image_size isz on 
istore.id = isz.imgid 

inner join size s 
on isz.isize = s.id 

inner join image_to_categories ic 
on istore.id = ic.imgid

inner join categories c
on ic.imgid = c.id

where s.id = 1 and istore.istatus = 1";